# Twitter Profile Image API deprecated

Tags: twitter

I am using Twitter API version 1 and replacing them to v1.1.
Then I cannot find users/profile_image/:screen_name API on version 1.1.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/shonanshachu
```

Does anyone know which API can be the best practice for replacing users/profile_image?
What I want is list of profile images or simple url with parameter of Twitter ID or screen name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will be useful for you. Those calls return all the info you need, including the image link. If you need only one user's image for a given user_id or user_screen, then you can read more from here:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/user-profile-images-and-banners

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json (you can replace followers with friends)

Comment: I guess this is the only way to get profile images from Twitter API. If anyone knows better API, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a great solution to this yet. The closest thing I have found is the [twitter API 1.1 docs for users/show](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show), but that is an authenticated call (requiring a user context) which is rate-limited (180 requests per 15 minutes). They mention this about getting the profile image url on the page about uploading a new photo:

> You can either update your local cache the next time you request the
>   user's information, or, at least 5 seconds after uploading the image,
>   ask for the updated URL using GET users/show.

I imagine once the 1.0 API is shut off in March 2013, this question will get a lot of votes. :)

There are [some hints](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/12098) that twitter is adding methods to their API to aid in retrieving images. We'll have to wait and see.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. API users/show has the limitation of request and the parameter "user_id" can only take 1 ID. I think this API will not solve the problem.I think similar question will come up after the API v1.0 shut off, too. But I want to mention this before they shut it off.