# How to get the list of favourite tweets, retweets and mentions of my tweets which are done by my followers and following?

Tags: wpf, api, twitter, tweetsharp

Basically i am developing a demo desktop application using TweetSharp library and wpf. I want the list of favourite tweets of my tweets which are favourited by my followers and following and same with the retweets and mentions just like the twitter has its user interaction or activity section in its website.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I don't know If is too late to response to your question. however you may find this post useful to start with.

How To Use Twitter v1.1 API

[Simplest PHP example for retrieving user_timeline with Twitter API version 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1/15314662#15314662)

Also find this other post here  Get twitter user profile picture Twitter v1.1 API

[How to get user image with Twitter API 1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836956/how-to-get-user-image-with-twitter-api-1-1)

Comment: @SharpCyber -- Thanks but I know how to start working with twitter api. My problem is am not getting the list of activities of my followers and following and I'm getting the notification of my followers and following activities through Streaming api of twitter.

Comment: to get both follower and following i guess you can use the https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json